# Remove array key prefix

Tags: php, arrays

I have this type of array what contains total income in each month:

```
Array ( [Total_Income_JAN] => 5000 [Total_Income_FEB] => 8000 [Total_Income_MAR] => 10000 )
```

How can I remove the prefix part from the array keys so that it becomes:

```
Array ( [JAN] => 4321 [FEB] => 2364 [MAR] => 2364 )
```

Comment: @zerkms foreach array index

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

$list  = Array("Total_Income_JAN" => 5000, "Total_Income_FEB" => 8000 , "Total_Income_MAR" => 10000);

function removePrefix(array $input) {

    $return = array();
    foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
        if (strpos($key, 'Total_Income_') === 0)
            $key = substr($key, 13);

        if (is_array($value))
            $value = removePrefix($value); 

        $return[$key] = $value;
    }
    return $return;
}

$list = removePrefix($list);
print_r($list);

?>
```

[Try Demo>>](http://codepad.viper-7.com/79dxAc)

Comment: See my answer for a universal non hardcoded solution based on this one.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66674845/4684797

Answer (score 5):

First, this solution is for `php 5.3.x` and higher versions.

It combines two arrays first being keys and second values from original array. Keys are transformed though using `array_map` so unneeded parts are removed using `str_replace`.

```
$my_array2 = array_combine(
  array_map(
    function($k) { return str_replace("Total_Income_", "", $k); }, 
    array_keys($my_array)
  ),
  array_values($my_array)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
foreach($my_array as $key => $value)
{
    $key2 = trim('Total_Income',$key); //or preg_replace('Total_income','',$key)
    $my_array2[$key2] = $value; 
}
print_r($my_array2);
```

Comment: that should be `trim($key, 'Total_Income');` and `str_replace` may be better suited for removing part of the string.

Comment: Nope trim('Total_Income',$key) is the correct syntax....see this http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: syntax is correct, but it doesn't what is wanted, try `php -r 'print trim("Total_Income", "Total_Income_FEB");'` and then reverse string positions

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$old_array = Array ( 'Total_Income_JAN' => 5000, 'Total_Income_FEB' => 8000, 'Total_Income_MAR' => 10000 );
$new_array = array();
foreach($old_array as $key=>$val){
    $new_key = preg_replace('#Total_Income_(.+)#i','$1',$key);
    $new_array[$new_key] = $val;
}
echo '<pre>';print_r($new_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an improved universal solution based on the answer from @VijayaPandey.
His method is hardcoded so I created a better solution:

Use the method like this:

```
$list  = Array("Total_Income_JAN" => 5000, "Total_Income_FEB" => 8000 , "Total_Income_MAR" => 10000);

$list = stripArrayKeyPrefix($list, "Total_Income_");
var_dump($list);

function stripArrayKeyPrefix(array $input, $prefix)
{
    $return = array();
    foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
        if (strpos($key, $prefix) === 0)
            $key = substr($key, strlen($prefix));

        if (is_array($value))
            $value = removePrefix($value, $prefix); 

        $return[$key] = $value;
    }
    return $return;
}
```

[Try the code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c82002a07f22290dc561f65d6acaff078d26a72e)

### Output:

```
array(3) {
  ["JAN"]=>
  int(5000)
  ["FEB"]=>
  int(8000)
  ["MAR"]=>
  int(10000)
}
```