# rewrite key value in foreach

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have such array and I need to convert it:

```
     Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0_mass] => 0.00
                [0_arm] => 287.02
                [0_max_limit] => 0.00
                [0_is_dom] => 0
            )
    
        [1] => Array
            (
                [1_mass] => 0.00
                [1_arm] => 269.24
                [1_max_limit] => 0.00
                [1_is_dom] => 0
            )
)
```

I need to receive the next one: So basically I need to delete "0_" these parts from each key. but it can be even "1000_". Only I think about is cutting string but it bad approach

```
  Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [mass] => 0.00
                [arm] => 287.02
                [max_limit] => 0.00
                [is_dom] => 0
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [mass] => 0.00
                [arm] => 269.24
                [max_limit] => 0.00
                [is_dom] => 0
            )
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can split the key name on `_` and eliminate the first part, just rebuild the rest.

Comment: @ADyson. I only find substr function in php. but second param need to be dynamic? Or I should use explode and split it by "_" ? Thanks!

Comment: You can use explode to split it into an array using _ as the separator, then re-combine all parts except the 0 element.

Comment: @ADyson, the `explode` function have third parameter for limit chunks, so we can avoid re-combining :)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16831459/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/48225782/2943403

Comment: Please always present your array data as `var_export()` output.  Please never edit your question to include a resolving approach -- that is what answers are for.

Comment: @Mrlucky I recommend this simpler solution https://3v4l.org/rQ3f3

Comment: Or without modifying by reference: https://3v4l.org/qbVt5

Answer (score 1):

You can use next approach:

```
$keys = array_map(function ($el) {
    $split = explode("_", $el);
    array_shift($split);
    return implode("_", $split);
}, array_keys($arr[0]));

//var_export($keys);

$res = array_map(function ($el) use ($keys) {
    return array_combine($keys, array_values($el));
}, $arr);
```

[Test PHP code online](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php8/e0a5d2c857ef897a59f9c00cb888c454/)

P.S. The above code works only in case all sub-arrays have same keys (except preifx)